# XML to JSON conversion dropping attributes

Tags: javascript, json, xml

My script works for the most part... it converts my xml into json. The problem is that the `id` attribute gets lost.

The script:

```
function xml2js(xml)
{
    try
    {
        let obj = {};
        if (xml.children.length == 0)
            obj = xml.textContent;
        else
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < xml.children.length; i++)
            {
                let item = xml.children.item(i);
                let nodeName = item.nodeName;

                if (obj[nodeName])
                {
                    if (typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined")
                    {
                        let old = obj[nodeName];

                        obj[nodeName] = [];
                        obj[nodeName].push(old);
                    }
                    obj[nodeName].push(xml2js(item));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.attributes)
                        for (let attribute of item.attributes)
                            obj[attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;

                    obj[nodeName] = xml2js(item);
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

I call it like so

```
const XMLDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(XMLString, "text/xml");
console.log(JSON.stringify(xml2js(XMLDoc), null, "\t"));
```

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smf>
    <lastTime>1694246241</lastTime>
    <topic id="78603">
        <icon><![CDATA[<div class="board_icon"><img src="http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png" alt=""></div>]]></icon>
        <subject>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78603.0&quot;&gt;Automated Test #14561&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;Started by &lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10&quot;&gt;Member 10&lt;/a&gt;  </subject>
        <board>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0&quot;&gt;Board Number 51&lt;/a&gt;</board>
        <replies><![CDATA[7 Replies<br>8 Views]]>></replies>
        <lastPost>
            <time ts="1694246241"><![CDATA[<strong>Today</strong> at 12:57 AM]]></time>
            <link><![CDATA[by <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=1">live627</a>D <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78603.new;topicseen#new" class="new_posts">New</a>]]></link>
        </lastPost>
    </topic>
    <topic id="78604">
        <icon><![CDATA[<div class="board_icon"><img src="http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png" alt=""></div>]]></icon>
        <subject>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78604.0&quot;&gt;Automated Test #14562&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;Started by &lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10&quot;&gt;Member 10&lt;/a&gt;  </subject>
        <board>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0&quot;&gt;Board Number 51&lt;/a&gt;</board>
        <replies><![CDATA[0 Replies<br>0 Views]]>></replies>
        <lastPost>
            <time ts="1693697618"><![CDATA[Sep 02, 2023, 04:33 PM]]></time>
            <link><![CDATA[by <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10">Member 10</a>D <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78604.new;topicseen#new" class="new_posts">New</a>]]></link>
        </lastPost>
    </topic>
    <topic id="78602">
        <icon><![CDATA[<div class="board_icon"><img src="http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png" alt=""></div>]]></icon>
        <subject>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78602.0&quot;&gt;Automated Test #14560&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;Started by &lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10&quot;&gt;Member 10&lt;/a&gt;  </subject>
        <board>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0&quot;&gt;Board Number 51&lt;/a&gt;</board>
        <replies><![CDATA[0 Replies<br>0 Views]]>></replies>
        <lastPost>
            <time ts="1693697618"><![CDATA[Sep 02, 2023, 04:33 PM]]></time>
            <link><![CDATA[by <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10">Member 10</a>D <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78602.new;topicseen#new" class="new_posts">New</a>]]></link>
        </lastPost>
    </topic>
</smf>
```

Expected output

```
{
    "smf": {
        "lastTime": "1694246241",
        "topic": [
            {
                "id": "78603",
                "icon": "<div class=\"board_icon\"><img src=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png\" alt=\"\"></div>",
                "subject": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78603.0\">Automated Test #14561</a><br>Started by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>  ",
                "board": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0\">Board Number 51</a>",
                "replies": "7 Replies<br>8 Views>",
                "lastPost": {
                    "ts": "1694246241",
                    "time": "Sep 09, 2023, 12:57 AM",
                    "link": "by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=1\">live627</a>D <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78603.new;topicseen#new\" class=\"new_posts\">New</a>"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "78604",
                "icon": "<div class=\"board_icon\"><img src=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png\" alt=\"\"></div>",
                "subject": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78604.0\">Automated Test #14562</a><br>Started by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>  ",
                "board": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0\">Board Number 51</a>",
                "replies": "0 Replies<br>0 Views>",
                "lastPost": {
                    "ts": "1693697618",
                    "time": "Sep 02, 2023, 04:33 PM",
                    "link": "by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>D <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78604.new;topicseen#new\" class=\"new_posts\">New</a>"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "78602",
                "icon": "<div class=\"board_icon\"><img src=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png\" alt=\"\"></div>",
                "subject": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78602.0\">Automated Test #14560</a><br>Started by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>  ",
                "board": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0\">Board Number 51</a>",
                "replies": "0 Replies<br>0 Views>",
                "lastPost": {
                    "ts": "1693697618",
                    "time": "Sep 02, 2023, 04:33 PM",
                    "link": "by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>D <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78602.new;topicseen#new\" class=\"new_posts\">New</a>"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Actual output

```
{
    "smf": {
        "lastTime": "1694246241",
        "id": "78603",
        "topic": [
            {
                "icon": "<div class=\"board_icon\"><img src=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png\" alt=\"\"></div>",
                "subject": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78603.0\">Automated Test #14561</a><br>Started by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>  ",
                "board": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0\">Board Number 51</a>",
                "replies": "7 Replies<br>8 Views>",
                "lastPost": {
                    "ts": "1694246241",
                    "time": "<strong>Today</strong> at 12:57 AM",
                    "link": "by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=1\">live627</a>D <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78603.new;topicseen#new\" class=\"new_posts\">New</a>"
                }
            },
            {
                "icon": "<div class=\"board_icon\"><img src=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png\" alt=\"\"></div>",
                "subject": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78604.0\">Automated Test #14562</a><br>Started by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>  ",
                "board": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0\">Board Number 51</a>",
                "replies": "0 Replies<br>0 Views>",
                "lastPost": {
                    "ts": "1693697618",
                    "time": "Sep 02, 2023, 04:33 PM",
                    "link": "by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>D <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78604.new;topicseen#new\" class=\"new_posts\">New</a>"
                }
            },
            {
                "icon": "<div class=\"board_icon\"><img src=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png\" alt=\"\"></div>",
                "subject": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78602.0\">Automated Test #14560</a><br>Started by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>  ",
                "board": "<a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0\">Board Number 51</a>",
                "replies": "0 Replies<br>0 Views>",
                "lastPost": {
                    "ts": "1693697618",
                    "time": "Sep 02, 2023, 04:33 PM",
                    "link": "by <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10\">Member 10</a>D <a href=\"http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78602.new;topicseen#new\" class=\"new_posts\">New</a>"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice how the `id` element should be added to the `topic` objects as is expected but is instead wrongly added to the top-level object.

Comment: If `id` should be inside `topic`, then to be consistent `ts` should be inside `time`

Comment: Attributes are not children nodes, they are "attribute" nodes. You need to treat them as such.

Comment: @Nick correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rearrange the code so the attributes are added to a current node, not a parent one, plus you need to add attributes to the siblings also.
- Take advantage of iterators to loop through children and attributes.
- Also you could have some design flaw when a text node doesn't have attributes. Maybe that's ok.

```js
const XMLDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(XMLString, "text/xml");
$pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(xml2js(XMLDoc), null, 4);

function xml2js(node){
    try {

        // collect attributes first
        const obj = [...node.attributes || []].reduce((r, attr) => (r[attr.nodeName] = attr.value, r), {});

        if (!node.children.length) {
            obj.content = node.textContent;
        } else
        
        for (const item of node.children){
            const {nodeName} = item, child = obj[nodeName];
            child ? 
              (Array.isArray(child) ? child : obj[nodeName] = [child]).push(xml2js(item)) : 
              obj[nodeName] = xml2js(item);
        }

        return obj;
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

```html
<script>
const XMLString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smf>
    <lastTime>1694246241</lastTime>
    <topic id="78603">
        <icon><![CDATA[<div class="board_icon"><img src="http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png" alt=""></div>]]></icon>
        <subject>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78603.0&quot;&gt;Automated Test #14561&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;Started by &lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10&quot;&gt;Member 10&lt;/a&gt;  </subject>
        <board>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0&quot;&gt;Board Number 51&lt;/a&gt;</board>
        <replies><![CDATA[7 Replies<br>8 Views]]>></replies>
        <lastPost>
            <time ts="1694246241"><![CDATA[<strong>Today</strong> at 12:57 AM]]></time>
            <link><![CDATA[by <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=1">live627</a>D <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78603.new;topicseen#new" class="new_posts">New</a>]]></link>
        </lastPost>
    </topic>
    <topic id="78604">
        <icon><![CDATA[<div class="board_icon"><img src="http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png" alt=""></div>]]></icon>
        <subject>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78604.0&quot;&gt;Automated Test #14562&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;Started by &lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10&quot;&gt;Member 10&lt;/a&gt;  </subject>
        <board>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0&quot;&gt;Board Number 51&lt;/a&gt;</board>
        <replies><![CDATA[0 Replies<br>0 Views]]>></replies>
        <lastPost>
            <time ts="1693697618"><![CDATA[Sep 02, 2023, 04:33 PM]]></time>
            <link><![CDATA[by <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10">Member 10</a>D <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78604.new;topicseen#new" class="new_posts">New</a>]]></link>
        </lastPost>
    </topic>
    <topic id="78602">
        <icon><![CDATA[<div class="board_icon"><img src="http://localhost/SMF2.1/Themes/default/images/post/xx.png" alt=""></div>]]></icon>
        <subject>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78602.0&quot;&gt;Automated Test #14560&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;Started by &lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10&quot;&gt;Member 10&lt;/a&gt;  </subject>
        <board>&lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?board=51.0&quot;&gt;Board Number 51&lt;/a&gt;</board>
        <replies><![CDATA[0 Replies<br>0 Views]]>></replies>
        <lastPost>
            <time ts="1693697618"><![CDATA[Sep 02, 2023, 04:33 PM]]></time>
            <link><![CDATA[by <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?action=profile;u=10">Member 10</a>D <a href="http://localhost/SMF2.1/index.php?topic=78602.new;topicseen#new" class="new_posts">New</a>]]></link>
        </lastPost>
    </topic>
</smf>`
</script>
<pre id="$pre"></pre>
```

Comment: `ts`  attribute  under `time` is dropped but must be kept.

Comment: @live627 thrn textContent sould have a name and present always or only when attributes exist. you didnt described that

Comment: Always; would probably be better to be consistent.

Comment: one final  question: I'm  unfamiliar with some syntax in `const {nodeName} = item, child = obj[nodeName];`, specifically `item, child`

Comment: @live627 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#syntax  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#declaration_with_destructuring

Comment: @live627 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment